# Iterating Map In JSTL from a specific index

Tags: jsp, dictionary, jstl

I want to iterate through a HasMap in JSTL.
I know it can be done by: `<c:foreach items=mymap>`

but I want to iterate through the map from a specific index to end. 
Like:

```
for(i=0;i<map.size;i++){
  for(j=i+1 ; j<=map.size;j++){
     key= something
     value = something

}
}
```

How can I iterate the map like this using JSTL , and how will I access the key and the value in a entry(keyvaluePair)?

Comment: how do the i and j variables get used to extract the key and value pairs? The keys in a `HashMap` are unordered, so iterating from a given index is tricky, unless the key is a number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `varStatus` to know the index of the current element in the `forEach` loop, and use `c:if` to ignore first elements.

For example to display a map starting from the fifth element:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${myMap}" varStatus="status">
  <c:if test="${status.index gt 4}">
     Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
     Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```